google search without SERP API
I need to perform 10,000 searches on Google, but I can't use the SERP API. Is there any free solution or package that I can use in my Nest.js project to achieve this? I’m using Puppeteer in my Nest.js project to perform multiple Google searches (around 10,000), but I’m concerned about my IP getting blocked. What are some strategies or techniques I can use to avoid getting blocked while making these requests? Are there any best practices, such as rotating proxies or using headless browsers, that you would recommend?
I attempted to make multiple requests using Puppeteer, but I noticed that after a certain number of searches, Google started blocking my IP.
I was hoping to find a way to perform a large number of Google searches (around 10,000) without getting my IP blocked.
I expected that Puppeteer might be able to handle this by using different techniques, but I’m not sure what the best approach is.

Yes, a rotating residential proxy will be a good effort. This is rather broad, though, and there are plenty of general purpose articles on this. Please make your question more specific to be on topic here.
